# Rails ActiveRecord::Relation Keeps Hitting the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple controller method:

```
products = Product.where(name: name, color: color, size: size, available: true)
```

Which returns a Product::ActiveRecord_Relation object. I want to take the first object and pull out a field e.g. `products.first.product_code`

But this and some other methods that I tried re-query the database. I've tried:

```
products[0].product_code
products.take.product_code
```

All of which re-query the database, hitting the database twice. Once for the where and one to take the field. Is there a simple solution that won't hit the db?

What does work is converting the ActiveRecord to an array (`products.to_a.[0].product_code`) but this seems inefficient.

Below is the server log to show the two separate hits:

[image]

Here is my controller method for reference:

```
  def update_selection
    size = params[:size]
    color = params[:color]
    name = params[:product_name]
    products = Product.where(name: name, color: color, size: size, available: true)
    product_code = products.empty? ? 'sold out' : products.first.product_code
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: { count: products.length, code: product_code}}
    end
  end
```

Comment: is `product_code` a field on Product?

Comment: product_code is a field in Product

Answer (score 6):

My best guess is that you're not actually hitting the database when assigning to `products`. ActiveRecord relations are lazy, meaning they don't query the database until the moment a result of that query is needed.

To put it in terms of your issue - this line:

`products = Product.where(name: name, color: color, size: size, available: true)`

doesn't require any data to actually be pulled from the db, so the query isn't carried out.

`products.first.product_code`, on the other hand, will cause a query to fire.

EDIT:

I believe the issue is coming from using `.exists?` (which is an ActiveRecord method that *always* fires a query). If you're checking to see if the query returned any results, try using `.present?` or `.any?` instead of `.exists?`.

EDIT 2:

OK, thanks for posting the code. You've got a couple options here.

1. Use `.to_a`:

`products = Product.where(name: name, color: color, size: size, available: true).to_a`

This loads all of the `products` into memory, which makes sense if you expect there to be a small number of products. This only fires one query.

2. You can change this line to only fire one query:

`product_code = products.first.try(:product_code) || 'sold out'`

This is more memory-efficient (since you're loading a maximum of one `product` into memory), but uses two queries (`products.count is the other one`).

Comment: That's what I thought too when I first was troubleshooting, but I am still getting two hits. I added the console log in the original question.

Comment: What I believe is happening is, because of lazy loading, when it gets to the product.first statement, it runs the initial where query to get the results and then the second query. Seems like the best option would be to eager load the Product.where...?

Comment: are you using `.exists?` somewhere in the controller?

Comment: I am not. I added the controller method to the original question for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this to be efficient, as it gets a SQL-based count, and then reruns a product query if required to get a single product.

Do you really want the "first" in the sense of the one with the lowest id? If so then use `first`, otherwise use `take`.

```
def update_selection
  size          = params[:size]
  color         = params[:color]
  name          = params[:product_name]
  products      = Product.where(name: name, color: color, size: size, available: true)
  product_count = products.count
  product_code  = product_count.zero? ? 'sold out' : products.take.product_code
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: { count: product_count, code: product_code}}
  end
end
```